# How to compare dates in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, date-comparison

I need to see if a date has more than X days. How can I do this in Python?

I have tested something like:

```
if datetime.date(2010, 1, 12) > datetime.timedelta(3):
```

I got the error:

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.date to datetime.timedelta
```

Any clue on how to achieve this?

Comment: "I need to see if a date have more than X days." What does that mean? That the day of month is greater than X? To get the day of month for a date, use the ``day`` attribute. ``if thedate.day > X:``

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't compare a [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime.html#date-objects) to a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects). A `timedelta` represents a duration, a `datetime` represents a specific point in time. The [difference](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime.html#available-types) of two `datetime`s is a `timedelta`. Datetimes are comparable with each other, as are `timedelta`s.

You have 2 options:

- Subtract another `datetime` from the one you've given, and compare the resulting `timedelta` with the `timedelta` you've also given.
- Convert the `timedelta` to a `datetime` by adding or subtracting it to another `datetime`, and then compare the resulting `datetime` with the `datetime` you've given.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing apples and oranges is always very hard! You are trying to compare "January 12, 2010" (a fixed point in time) with "3 hours" (a duration). There is no sense in this.

If what you are asking is "does my `datetime` fall after the nth day of the month" then you can do :

```
my_important_date = datetime.now()

if my_important_date.day > n:
    pass #do you important things
```