# Python - Is current time within two datetime values

Tags: python, datetime

I've looked around here for a while trying all different kinds of accepted answers, but they are too irrelevant for my own needs and 90% require static typing of the current date which is something I don't want to do

**Context**

Quite simple.

Get the current time in Spain.

Have a variable already set up which is an agreed start time.

Have a variable already set up which is an agreed end time.

If the current time in Spain is between the start-end time, proceed with saving logs

**Threads checked for solution to my problem**

All useless, downvoted, or irrelevant due to static typing of datetime

[Python current time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python)

[Compare dates Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7873013/how-to-compare-dates-in-python)

[Convert string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672629/python-how-to-convert-string-into-datetime)

[Compare date and datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278999/how-can-i-compare-a-date-and-a-datetime-in-python)

[Check if time is between two days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44641409/python-check-if-time-is-in-range-between-two-days)

[Convert string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

[Compare if datetime.timedelta is between two values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28288059/compare-if-datetime-timedelta-is-between-two-values)

**Code so far**

```
now_time_uk = datetime.datetime.now()
current_time_spain = now_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
start = datetime.time(10, 50)
end = datetime.time(16, 00)

if current_time_spain >= start or current_time_spain <= end:
    print('Start logging')
else:
    print('No need to log')
```

The code above was extracted from a thread on S.O which was an accepted answer, when I ran this, it gives a TypeError

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to datetime.time
```

**Accepted Answer Code**

```
now_time_uk = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now_time_uk)
current_time_spain = now_time_uk + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
start = datetime.time(10, 50)
end = datetime.time(17, 00)
print(current_time_spain.time())

if current_time_spain.time() >= start and current_time_spain.time() <= end:
    print('Start logging')
else:
    print('No need to log')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says you are trying to compare `datetime` objects with `time` objects which isn't possible... luckily the `datetime` object has a builtin method for converting to a `time` object, and that is `.time()`. So you can replace:

```
if current_time_spain >= start or current_time_spain <= end:
```

With

```
if current_time_spain.time() >= start or current_time_spain.time() <= end:
```

And it should work. Another way of doing it is setting `current_time_spain` from the beginning as a `time` object or another option is to set the `start` and `end` times to be `datetime` objects instead of `time`

Comment: Will this adequately cover when the end time is on a different day? (Ex: Start time 10pm 06/05 / End time 3am 06/06) ?

Comment: No it will not, but that's because your logic doesn't do that either, is 22:00 higher then 01:00 or lower? It has to be one or the other, it can't be both (or it will give you no results anyway). If you need to cross days like that I suggest you use the 3rd option I mentioned and work only with full `datetime` objects and not just `time` (That way you can compare `now` with "**tomorrow** at 2am")

Comment: I'll add the datetime objects as an iteration down the line, the basic functionality works now thanks to converting to time object

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing `datetime` object with date & time with only `time` , as mentioned in error

`datetime.datetime.now()` this returns datetime whereas `datetime.time(10, 50)` returns time.

If you want to only compare time then why you don't simply compare hours and minutes from `now()`

Comment: The agreed time may change depending on server activity, it may end up going overnight, so it would start at 11pm and finish at 3am the next day

Comment: Ok then maybe you can make a datetime  object with day, month, year from now() and then compare that ? In that case both will be datetime

Answer (score 0):

You can’t compare a date time within a time but you could continue to use a TimeDelta in order to create a *start* and *end* date to compare. With this solution your code could become:

```
now_time_uk = date time.datetime.now()
current_time_spain = now_time + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
start_hours = 10
start_minutes = 50
end_hours = 16
end_minutes = 0
time_spain_start = current_time_spain + datetime.timedelta(hours=start_hours, minutes=start_minutes)
time_spain_end = current_time_spain + datetime.timedelta(hours=end_hours, minutes=end_minutes)

if current_time_spain >= time_spain_start or current_time_spain <= spain_time_end:
    print “Start logging”
else:
    print “No need to log”
```

In this way you can also add a variable for each parameter of the TimeDelta object in order to have different time for the end date even if the day is the next or whatever you want or need. We can imagine to have all variable *days*, *hours*, *minutes*, and *seconds* initialized to the 0 value, so you need to change only the value you need.